# Setting cookie in iframe when using safari

Tags: javascript, cookies, iframe, safari

I know that there were lots of related questions and answers on Stackoverflow and over the internet, however, I was not able to find the solution for my case.

We have an application on domain A that we have no control over, and application on domain B - our iframe that is being integrated into application A. We use cookies in our application B. All works fine, cookies are preserved between requests, except Safari. I read https://gist.github.com/iansltx/18caf551baaa60b79206 and understood that Safari is special and requires that a user interacted with domain B explicitly in the past.

We tried to overcome the issue by trying to render an invisible pixel on site A that employs our integration JS script that injects an iframe into some div on site A. Also we tried to make a CORS ajax request to domain A to domain B (also from our integration script), we do use withCrendetials:true, if it matters, and the request successfully returns the "set-cookie" header, but the cookie is not getting passed into further requests from iframe to our domain B.

But if I open domain B explicitly, suddenly cookies are getting passed in our iframe integrated into domain A.

I think we've tried everything that we could come up with so far, but no luck. Some resources suggest using JS redirects, but it's bad user experience, I think. I was hoping for a better solution.

Any pointers are highly appreciated. Please, save my day, this issue drives me crazy :)

Answer (score 1):

By doing lots of research we concluded that it's better to get rid of cookies and use an Authorization header explicitly. There was just 1 problem left: the images that we inserted via  into DOM, and therefore we could not pass an Authorization header there (using query parameters was not ideal since it would expose the auth token). We solved this problem by doing ajax requests to image URLs and inserting them as blobs into DOM.